# $(id).html() not working in ajax success

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to change the html text using `jquery` `ajax` that return `json array`. In the php file i use `echo` `json.encode()` to return the `json array object`. everything looks good in `console`. but when i tried to use the data to change text in html it does work. please help this lamo T.T

```
  var request = $.ajax({
      url:"userEditChanges/submitTestRequirementModalForm.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:formData,
      dataType:"json",

      success:function(data)
      { 
        for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
          console.log(data[index]);  
        }
        console.log(data);
        // $('#textreqline' ).html("lo")
        //document.getElementById("textreqline") return null.
        document.getElementById("textreqline").innerHTML = "hello";
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
      }
      })
      });
```

getElementById return null in console. same goes with jquery selector. but if i write

```
document.getElementById("textreqline").innerHTML = "hello";
```

or

```
 $('#textreqline' ).html("lo");
```

outside the `ajax` success function the html text in page will change. it's like `ajax` preventing from their own selector from functioning. i also tried create a function with `.html()` in it and call at ajax success as function and still not working.

Comment: echo json_encode('your_data');

and exit(); php script
submitTestRequirementModalForm.php

Comment: What's the code you're actually trying to use to update the html of your textreqline, that's not working?

Comment: @crazysj it does'nt work either..

Comment: @duncan  $('#textreqline' ).html("lo") now working (even i change to javascript style also not working).

Comment: document.getElementById("textreqline").innerHTML = "hello";  if i use this code, the console shown null.

Comment: if in ajax it doesn't find your element , you can save you DOM in your variable like this ver $elm= document.getElementById("textreqline") then use $elm in your ajax

Comment: Are you sure the `textreqline` exists before you run the AJAX call? (aka are you using `$( document ).ready()`?)

Comment: @masoumehmiran if i save the id outside ajax function, it said the variable not define.. p/s: i save outside the ajax into var and use alert (outside the ajax), i pop up 2 times, first time is undefine but second time it pop the id. why is that?

Comment: @TiiJ7 yes it exists. the code inside ajax function run well outside ajax function. i also did use $(document).ready();  it's being 2 days i working on this, tiresome

Comment: here i link the file. from index.php i use iframe linked to main.php. from main i link script.js and ajax called to submitTestRequirementModelForm.php. the data return vise versa

Comment: the text (html) is in the main.php

Comment: @sone i think your DOM is not load when you call ajax, please check  does it exist before call ajax not? this problem when occurs when your DOM is not in your document

Comment: @masoumehmiran it's loaded actually. caused of iframe, i need to use .content().find(). do refer my code posted. thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i manage to find a way! i need to use .content().find() because browser read iframe differently (please do correct me if i misunderstood the concept).

p/s:not forget to thank you for you all contributions, motivated lol.

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url:"userEditChanges/submitTestRequirementModalForm.php",
  method:"POST",
  data:formData,
  dataType:"json",

  success:function(data)
  { 
    var arr = "";
    data.forEach(function(params) {
     arr = arr+ "<p>" + params + " <p>";   
    });


    $('#iview').contents().find('#textreqlinebaru').each(function (params) {
      $(this).html(arr);
    });
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
  }
  }
```